# Origin shift in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to shift the origin in such a way as the following code will cause the circle to appear with center at the point marked in red.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shift={(0,0)}]
\begin{axis}[ 
    ticks=none,
    axis lines = middle,
    axis line style={->},
    ymin=0,
    xmin=-3,
    xmax=3,
    xlabel={$Y$},
    ylabel={$\pi$}]
\addplot[black, domain=-2:2] {x+3};
\addplot[red,mark=*] coordinates {(0,3)};
\node[coordinate, pin=0:{target}] at (axis cs:0.5, 3){};
\end{axis}
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution 1

Suppose you already know the coordinate at which you want to put the circle, which is `(axis cs:0,3)`. You can just draw a circle placing a `node` at that coordinate, i.e.

```
\node[draw,circle,inner sep=0,miminum size=1cm] at(axis cs:0,3){};
```

## Solution 2

Alternatively, you can name the node, say `target`, and then can draw the circle at `(target)` with

```
\draw (target) circle[radius=1];
```

## Solution 3

Suppose the coordinate where you want to put the circle needs to be calculated. Then you can use the `intersections` library to calculate that point:

- Name the line `{x+3}` by adding `name path global=line` to the `\addplot` command:

  ```
  \addplot[black, domain=-2:2,name path global=line] {x+3};
  ```
- Name the vertical axis

  ```
  \path[name path global=yaxis](axis cs:0,0)--(axis cs:0,5);
  ```
- And draw the circle using

  ```
  \draw[name intersections={of=line and yaxis, by=target}](target)circle[radius=1];
  ```

## Full code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shift={(0,0)}]
\begin{axis}[ 
    ticks=none,
    axis lines = middle,
    axis line style={->},
    ymin=0,
    xmin=-3,
    xmax=3,
    xlabel={$Y$},
    ylabel={$\pi$}]
\addplot[black, domain=-2:2,name path global=line] {x+3};
% \path[name path global=yaxis](axis cs:0,0)--(axis cs:0,5);
\addplot[red,mark=*] coordinates {(0,3)};
\node(target)[pin=0:{target},draw,circle,inner sep=0,minimum size=1cm] at (axis cs:0,3){};
\end{axis}
% \draw (target) circle[radius=1];
% \draw[name intersections={of=line and yaxis, by=target}](target)circle[radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 8):

What you are searching for is actually the point where you "grab" the axis.

This, in turn, is a general feature available for every tikz node: whenever you place a tikz node, you have to provide the `at` key to say where to place it and you have to provide an `anchor` where to grab the node (i.e. which position inside of the node is to be placed at the position specified by `at`).

The same is true for an axis (as an axis is essentially a special kind of tikz node).

By default, an axis has `at={(0,0)}`. We only need to adopt the `anchor`. To this end, you can simply assign the name "target" to your target coordinate and use `anchor=target`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shift={(0,0)}]
\begin{axis}[ 
    anchor=target,
    ticks=none,
    axis lines = middle,
    axis line style={->},
    ymin=0,
    xmin=-3,
    xmax=3,
    xlabel={$Y$},
    ylabel={$\pi$}]
\addplot[black, domain=-2:2] {x+3};
\addplot[red,mark=*] coordinates {(0,3)};
\node[coordinate, pin=0:{target}] (target) at (axis cs:0, 3){};
\end{axis}
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=1];

\fill (0,0) circle[radius=1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]